# Multiple args with arg4j

Tags: java, args4j

I have a parameter which I need to parse from command line. I use for this arg4j of version 2.0.23. I need to parse path parameter and in command line can be specified one or more path's. So I need to parse multiple params. Here's the way I find:

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Option(name = "-p", required = true)
public void addPath(String arg) {list.add(arg);}
```

It works ok. But I want to know is it correct or there is a better way? 
I've googled that in version 2.0.13 there was parameter multipleValue in @Option, but seems now it's gone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
import org.kohsuke.args4j.spi.StringArrayOptionHandler;

@Option(name = "-p", handler = StringArrayOptionHandler.class, required = true)
private List<String> list;
```

which should allow

```
-p arg1 arg2 ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't the type be `String[]` as suggested in the [javadoc](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/apidocs/org/kohsuke/args4j/spi/StringArrayOptionHandler.html)?

Comment: There seems to be an automatic conversion. It works like outlined above.